# opcua problems about read and browse

Tags: python, opc-ua

Through wireshark, I captured a segment of the data transmission message between the opcua server and the client in dewesoft. I plan to use python as a client to implement the same message according to the message to achieve similar functions. However, in the process of interaction between the program I wrote and the server, there are some differences in the message, and I don't know how to modify my code.

First, read node values,this is my code:

```
node_id = "ns=0;i=2259"
node = client.get_node(node_id)
data_value = node.get_value()
```

This is the message I implemented:[image: my]

This is the message dewesoft implemented:[image: dewesoft]

Next,browse nodes,This is my code:

```
node_id=client.get_node("i=84")
node_id_child0 = node_id.get_children()
```

This is the message I implemented:[image: my]

This is the message dewesoft implemented:[image: dewesoft]

I want to know how to implement a message like dewesoft, and how to modify my code. I have looked up a lot of information and still have no clue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to asyncua, there the message should match. Also i wouldn't care about these minimal different messages, it makes no sense to match them. For example the nodeid mean the same.

Comment: The reason I want to match the message, this is because the client of dewesoft reads a value node by implementing a series of read, browse and callmethod messages. I also want to get the value of that node, but I can't read the value of that node right now, this is an error in my python code“The node id refers to a node that does not exist in the server address space."(BadNodeIdUnknown)”,this is an error read by uaexpert also. But dewesoft's own clients can read it. So I think the matching message, make it completely consistent and may be able to read the value of this node.@Schroeder

Comment: The server has a bug if it sees any difference between the nodeIds in your examples. Regardless of the encoding byte, the values represent the same NodeId. Good client libraries know this fact, and for this reason they will *not* let you change how precisely the nodeId is encoded, because there is absolutely no reason to do so, with compliant servers. And bothering with non-compliant servers is usually not worth the extra effort and complications on the client side.